# Function template overload resolution, dependent and non-dependent parameters

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, language-lawyer

Given the following program

```
#include <iostream>

template<class T> struct id { using type = T; };

template<class T1, class T2>
int func(T1, T2) { return 0; }

template<class T1, class T2>
int func(typename id<T1>::type, typename id<T2>::type) { return 1; }

int main()
{
    std::cout << func<int, int>(0, 0) << std::endl;
}
```

GCC and Clang both prints `1` for this program. Is this program guaranteed to print `1` by the standard?

I tried finding the answer [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/function_template#Function_template_overloading) but couldn't decipher it. It looks like the function templates might be equivalent and therefore breaks ODR but I'm not sure.

Does changing the second function template to

```
template<class T>
using id_type = typename id<T>::type;

template<class T1, class T2>
int func(id_type<T1>, id_type<T2>) { return 1; }
```

make a difference?

Comment: I would say the second `func` is more specialized since it could bring to a substitution failure if you specialize `id` (e.g. with `template<> struct id<int> {};`). So no ODR violation. But I think you should give some context on the use case, because without further info, don't do that :D

Comment: @Bérenger Note that if we do not use explicit template argument specification (`func(0, 0);` on the call site) and instead attempt to rely on template argument deduction (`func(0, 0);` on the call site) , the `0`-returning overload is picked. My first guess (deleted answer) was also that the `1`-returning overloads is more specialized than the other one, but now I'm leaning more towards this being an ODR-violation, unless there's some special clause with dependent names (`typename id<T1>::type` dependent).

Comment: I edited the question to add an example use case for the concept in mind

Comment: @Mestkon Imho I think the edit just adds unnecessary confusion to the question. In the expanded example the `add_const2` is a _transformation trait_ that actually CV-qualifies the `Func` template argument. This is no conflict: if you remove that overload the call `something<void(float)>(&S::f2);` wont even compile; you would need to explicitly specify the const-ness (`something<void(float) const>(&S::f2);`). Your original question is interesting, though, where the `id`(entity) class template is simply wrapping the template type parameter into an alias. I would suggest reverting the last edit.

Comment: You are correct, my mistake

Comment: Tangent: C++20 is adding the class template `std::type_identity` and `std::type_identity_t` which are just like the `id` and `id_type` here. One common use of such a thing is to intentionally put a template parameter in a non-deduced context. This can be useful if the same parameter appears more than once and you want it to be deduced from only one or some of those places, and then just substituted in to the others.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is bog-standard partial ordering. We substitute unique types into one of the function templates and try to deduce the other against it. Do it both ways and if deduction only succeeds in one direction, we have an order. If you want to read the arcane rules, see [temp.func.order] and [temp.deduct.partial].

So here,

- Substituting `T1=U1, T2=U2` into the first overload's function type produces `int f(U1, U2);` Can we deduce `T1` and `T2` in the second overload from this? No; both are in non-deduced contexts. Ergo, deduction fails.
- Substituting `T1=U1, T2=U2` into the second overload produces `int f(id<U1>::type, id<U2>::type)` (this is conducted in the definition context so we can't substitute further into `id` - there may be a specialization somewhere). Can we deduce the `T1` and `T2` in the first overload from this? Yes, by deducing `T1 = id<U1>::type` and `T2 = id<U2>::type`. Deduction succeeds.

Since deduction succeeds only in one direction - deducing the first from transformed second - the second is more specialized than the first and is preferentially picked by overload resolution.

The alias template case changes nothing.

---

These templates are neither equivalent nor functionally equivalent.

Comment: Thanks, this is much easier to understand :)

Comment: Sorry to add another prompt, but I'm really curious about how the rules of template argument deduction applies in a non-deduced context, where the call is moreover fully using explicit template argument specification. Specifically, in `func(typename id<T1>::type, typename id<T2>::type)` both `T1` and `T2` are in non-deduced contexts, and the overload would not even be a _viable function_ for overload resolution if we did not use explicit template argument specification (e.g. not viable for `func(0, 0)`). Does [temp.deduct.partial] and [temp.func.order] still apply?

Answer (score 3):

The following `func` overload

> ```
> // Denote as overload F.
> template<class T1, class T2>
> int func(typename id<T1>::type, typename id<T2>::type) { return 1; }
> ```

is *more specialized* than the following `func` overload

> ```
> // Denote as overload G.
> template<class T1, class T2>
> int func(T1, T2) { return 0; }
> ```

thus, the former is chosen by overload resolution.

---

<sub>*(All ISO Standard references below refer to [N4659: March 2017 post-Kona working draft/C++17 DIS](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/))*</sub>

The partial ordering of the `G` and `F` overloads of `func` is governed by:

- [[temp.func.order]/2](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/temp.func.order#2), [[temp.func.order]/3](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/temp.func.order#3) and  [[temp.func.order]/4](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/temp.func.order#4), and
- [[temp.deduct.partial]/2](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/temp.deduct.partial#2) and [[temp.deduct.partial]/10](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/temp.deduct.partial#10).